# Kafka spark streaming integration

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I have setup Kafka and spark streaming using maven in my system. I would like to know any suggestions that could help me do wider operations apart from typing something in the producer and seeing it in the consumers .

How can I create a source that puts data like json or avro into Kafka producer continuously and so I can process it with spark and perform some operations out of it  . Need suggestions how can I design this

Comment: give us more details on the source of your data

Comment: I'm considering to give source as avro or protobuf

Comment: And I'm just doing it as an exercise.i have to create a source myself

Comment: I deleted my answer as it is uncorrelated, then. Have you already got your hands on the directory watch? That could be a way

Comment: Directory watch ? I don't get you buddy. Sorry

Comment: have a look at this fileStream: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-sources

Comment: Is there a way I can make the data to be feed to Kafka producer continuously

Answer (score 0):

Please find the link below.

https://github.com/hortonworks-gallery/tutorials/blob/master/2015-09-26-transporting-real-time-event-stream-with-apache-kafka.md

This is an HDP tutorial.. If you are not using HDP stack.. please ignore the initial part of the tutorial..

It is having a Kafka producer through a jar file you can generate

In this tutorial uses a Java API to produce Truck events using New York City Truck Routes (kml) file.

You need to download the data file and Java code and jar file ..

Details are in the tutorial

Hope this helps